# Angular CDK Drag and Drop Issue with Form Groups

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm working on implementing drag-and-drop functionality for form groups in my Angular application using the Angular CDK. While I've successfully enabled the dragging and dropping of individual fields between form groups, I encountered an issue when attempting to drag and drop entire form groups. Specifically, when dropping a form group, the **`currentIndex`** is consistently showing as 0, while the **`previousIndex`** is correct.

I've already implemented dragging and dropping functionality for individual fields within form groups using Angular CDK, which is working as expected. To extend this functionality to form groups themselves, I modified the code to handle the dropping of entire form groups.
My HTML code -

```
<div cdkDropListGroup class="overall-container flex-row">
  <div class="flex-grow admin-grid-layout padding-right-regular" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropGroup($event)">
    <div cdkDrag *ngFor="let group of dummyFormData.fieldGroups; let i = index" class="entity-form-cell admin-form-column section-container">
      <app-admin-section-header [(title)]="group.header" (remove)="removeGroup(i)"></app-admin-section-header>
      <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="group.fields" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="fields-group-list drop-list">
        <div *ngFor="let field of group.fields" class="admin-form-field flex-row align-center" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".overall-container">
          <div class="dummy-form-field"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entity-form-cell admin-form-column">
      <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropNewGroup($event)" class="fields-group-list drop-list drop-area-hint">
        drop here to create new field group
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-card class="toolbar">
    <mat-card-content cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListData]="dummyFormData.availableFields" class="drop-list">
      <div class="drop-area-hint"></div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

My ts code -

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<ColumnConfig[], ColumnConfig[]>) {
    console.log(this.config.fieldGroups)
    const prevFieldsArray = event.previousContainer.data;
    const newFieldsArray = event.container.data;

    if (
      prevFieldsArray[event.previousIndex] === this.createNewFieldPlaceholder
    ) {
      this.dropNewField(event);
      return;
    }

    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(newFieldsArray, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        prevFieldsArray,
        newFieldsArray,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex,
      );
    }

    if (newFieldsArray === this.availableFields) {
      // ensure available fields have consistent order
      this.initAvailableFields();
    }
  }
dropGroup(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
  moveItemInArray(
    dummyFormData.fieldGroups,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex,
  );
}

dropNewGroup(event: CdkDragDrop<any, any>) {
  const newCol = { fields: [] };
  dummyFormData.fieldGroups.push(newCol);
  event.container.data = newCol.fields;
  dropGroup(event);
}

removeGroup(i: number) {
  const [removedFieldGroup] = dummyFormData.fieldGroups.splice(i, 1);
  // additional logic if needed
}
```

**Data Array:**

```
const dummyFormData = {
  fieldGroups: [
    {
      fields: ['photo'],
      header: "Personal Information"
    },
    {
      fields: ['name', 'projectNumber', 'admissionDate'],
      header: "Additional"
    },
    {
      fields: ['dateOfBirth', 'birth_certificate', 'gender', 'motherTongue'],
      header: "Additional"
    },
    {
      fields: ['center', 'status', 'address', 'phone'],
      header: "Scholar activities"
    }
  ],
  availableFields: ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], // Example available fields
  createNewFieldPlaceholder: 'createNewFieldPlaceholder' // Placeholder for creating new fields
};
```

**Expected Outcome:**

When dropping a form group, I expected the **`currentIndex`** to accurately represent the position where the form group was dropped within the list of form groups. However, despite correctly updating the **`previousIndex`**, the **`currentIndex`** consistently showed as 0, regardless of where I dropped the form group.